# How do I choose only one branch of ArcTan?

Tags: plotting, trigonometry

I have a problem concerning `ArcTan` drawing a graph using `ListPlot`. I import a table of data:

```
a = Import["D:\2_b=10a.txt", "Table"];
```

Then I write:

```
ListPlot[Table[{i*0.005 Pi, -ArcTan[(a[[i]][[1]] - 
   a[[i - 1]][[1]]), (a[[i]][[2]] - a[[i - 1]][[2]])]}, {i, 2, 401, 1}]], PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, {-4, 4}}]
```

The returned graph looks like

[image: this]

I know from the nature of my calculations that the function must be continuous on the interval $[0,Pi]$, but at $3Pi/4$ the `ArcTan` function goes to another branch, since `ArcTan[x,y]` chooses a quadrant. How could I possibly try to move the bottom part of the plot up by Pi, so the function is smooth and continuous?

I tried defining a function

```
myArcTan[x_] := Piecewise[{{ArcTan[x] + Pi, x < 0}, {ArcTan[x], x > 0}}];
```

but it doesn't work. Thank you very much.

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33679/how-to-represent-a-continuous-monotonic-phase-of-airy-functions) or [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56249/fourier-analysis-how-to-get-rid-of-a-discontinuity) might help.

Comment: Please upload your data or provide a self-contained example.